Exercise 11.1 in Algebraic Combinatorics by Stanley
Let $\mathcal{C}_{D} = \mathcal{C}$ denote the cycle space, or the space of all circulations, on some digraph $D = \left(V,E\right)$. Recall that a circulation is a function $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
$\sum\limits_{\substack{{e \in E} \\ \operatorname{init}(e) = v}} f(e) = \sum\limits_{\substack{{e \in E} \\ \operatorname{fin}(e) = v}} f(e)$ for all $v \in V$,
where $\operatorname{init}(e)$ and $\operatorname{fin}(e)$ denote the source and the target of an edge $e$. Here we assume that each edge $e \in E$ is assigned some fixed orientation.
Let $C_n$ denote the $n$-dimensional hypercube, and $\mathfrak{o}$ denote some orientation of $C_n$.

Exercise 11.1(b): Show that $\mathcal{C}_{C_n}$ is spanned by the circulations $f_C$ given by
$$f_C(e)
= \begin{cases}
    1, &\text{if } e \in C \text{ and } e \text{ agree with } \mathfrak{o}, \\
    -1, &\text{if } e \in C \text{ and } e \text{ is opposite to } \mathfrak{o}, \\
    0, &\text{otherwise,}
\end{cases}$$
where $C$ is a circuit of length 4.

By Corollary 11.7, for a digraph $D = (V, E)$ with $p$ vertices, $q$ edges, and $k$ connected components (as an undirected graph). Then \begin{align*}
    \dim \mathcal{C} &= q - p + k.
\end{align*} So in this case, $\dim{\mathcal{C}} = n2^{n - 1} - 2^n + 1$.
My attempt: \begin{align*}
n2^{n - 1} - 2^n + 1 &= \frac{n2^n - 2^{n + 1}}{2} + 1.
\end{align*} Then we can combinatorially interpret $n2^n$ to be selecting which vertex to start on and choosing a direction for the first (and thus, last) step of the length 4 circuit. Furthermore, we can interpret the 2 in the denominator as dividing out by the orientation of each circuit. However, I am not sure where to go from here... any help would be greatly appreciated!

What is $D$ and what is a circulation?

A circulation is a function $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\sum_{\substack{{e \in E} \ \text{init}(e) = v}} f(e) = \sum_{\substack{{e \in E} \ \text{fin}(e) = v}} f(e)$$ for every vertex $v$. init and fin refer to the initial and final verticies of a directed edge, respectively.
